# What is special about the lifetime of objects created in MFC's InitInstance function?

Tags: c++, mfc, object-lifetime

I see several code examples showing variables and object creations inside of the `InitInstance()` function of an MFC appObject (i.e. `theApp`).  I thought anything created inside a function dies when the function exits. And the `InitInstance` function does appear to exit prior to the program exiting, just after showing the windows.

What am I missing? How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: objects created at function scope with automatic storage duration will be automatically destroyed when the function exists.

There are two possible explanations for what you're seeing (it's hard to narrow it down any more than that since you didn't include any example code with your question):

1. The objects are actually being created using the `new` keyword, which means that they have dynamic storage duration and are not automatically destroyed. Instead, they must be manually destroyed using the `delete` keyword. In addition to seeing `new`, a dead giveaway of this style is the use of pointers—`new` returns a pointer to the new object, so you'll see `*` all over the place.
2. The object doesn't actually *need* to exist any longer than the function in which it is declared. It might be temporarily created just so that some of its member functions can be called. The effects of these member functions are global or have effects beyond the class object itself. This is rather common in MFC, since most of the classes are wrappers around the Win32 API.

   For example, the `CWnd` class is just an object-oriented wrapper around a Win32 window, represented by an `HWND` (or handle to a window). You can create a `CWnd` object, use it to create and manipulate a Windows window (`HWND`), and then allow it to be destroyed without affecting the underlying Windows window. The "Remarks" section of the [`CWnd` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h.aspx) talks a bit about this confusing behavior:

   > A `CWnd` object is distinct from a Windows window, but the two are tightly linked. A `CWnd` object is created or destroyed by the `CWnd` constructor and destructor. The Windows window, on the other hand, is a data structure internal to Windows that is created by a `Create` member function and destroyed by the `CWnd` virtual destructor. The `DestroyWindow` function destroys the Windows window without destroying the object.

You did mention the ubiquitous `theApp` object in your question, though. That one is a little different—it's actually a *global* object because it is not declared inside of any function's scope. It is automatically constructed when the program begins executing, and automatically destroyed when the program ends.

Comment: Well I hope I'm replying (Add Comment) in the correct way, this forum is bit different than other type forums I've used. Also how do I give you a rep point for your effort etc, I don't see that readily anywhere unless Vote is that ?

Comment: Also I just learned you can't do a line return in a comment, hence the run on reply,.... Yes it is the "new" scenarios and/or mfc dynamic macros which eventually are the same thing as new along with runtime class etc. But even though I understand the aspect of the object being created on the heap having program lifetime, what is confusing me is the ptrs that are being created and used for the return from new objects are "apparently" also inside the InitInstance. Wouldn't these have to be declared outside the InitInstance for them not to die on func exit. Appreciate your input.

Comment: The pointers that are set using 'new' in the standard InitInstance code are copied into MFC structures, then the stack-based original pointer is indeed discarded when InitInstance returns. For example, pDocTemplate is initialized using 'new', then it is tested for NULL, and if not NULL it is passed to AddDocTemplate, which stores a copy for eventual deletion.

Comment: Oh ok, well thanks to both you guys I am starting to see what's going on now. So it's up to me to store it, "if I need that particular ptr" later, that is if I can't get it from the mfc stored framework which admittedly most times I could thru the AfxGetApp->etc. So now having all this illuminated I can now see the most of the code scenarios I've been looking at were doing as said above OR they simply made no mention of the storing if needed. Probably the former, but now it's a bit more clear in my mind. Thank you both.

Comment: I see the check mark now, I think my browser is not in the compatability view on this forum. Also how does one give a reply a reputation point or is that also what the vote check does  ?  I.e. I notice that if another reply comes in the comment thread (like Scott) then does the vote take care of them both ?

Comment: @RWB I'm glad that you found my answer helpful. You're right about this site working a bit differently, but I think you'll find that it's for the best. Since you're a new user, you should have seen [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) when you first visited. If not, it's worth looking through. It explains a lot of the different and confusing stuff about the site. There is also a [FAQ].